# Poles of an Algebraic Function defined by a multivariate polynomial system

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, singularity

Consider the following multivariate polynomial system, which defines $x(s)$ and $y(s)$,

$$s - y \, ( s x + x - 1) = 0$$
$$s - x \, ( s y + y - 1) = 0$$

One may describe $x$ and $y$ as functions of $s$ by finding their implicit equations using any technique of polynomial elimination,

$$\Phi_1(x,s) = (s+1) \, x^2 - x - s = 0$$

$$\Phi_2(y,s) = (s+1) \, y^2 - y - s = 0$$

Implicit function theorem implies that there is a pole candidate at $s=-1$.

That is my question: there is a general way to study the poles of an algebraic function defined by a multivariate polynomial system without explicitly obtaining its implicit equation? The whole point here is trying to skip the time-consuming elimination process (to the best of my knowledge only algorithms based on Resultants or Gröbner Basis can be used).

Comment: Just a comment: the algebraic set defined by your system of polynomials is reducible. Its irreducible components are a translate of the $s$-axis given by $x = y = 1$ and another genus $0$ curve given by $x = y$, $sx + x + s = 0$. These components intersect at $(x,y,s) = (1,1,-1/2)$. On the first component $x$ doesn't have a pole at $s = -1$ since $x = 1$ is constant. On the other component we have $x = -s/(s+1)$ which certainly has a pole at $s = -1$, but I don't know how to see this without doing the elimination.